# Displaying unit test results in VS 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

I am a rookie was using the Visual Studio 2008 built-in Unit Testing components, what would be the best way to record or display your results in a unit test?

I want to test my service method when it returns a System.GUID and an empty System.GUID

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetGUID()
{
   MyWcfServiceService.MyWcfServiceClient proxy = new MyWcfServiceService.MyWcfServiceClient();
   string name = "HasGuid";

   System.GUID guid = proxy.GetGUID(name);
}

[TestMethod]
public void GetEmptyGUID()
{
    MyWcfServiceService.MyWcfServiceClient proxy = new MyWcfServiceService.MyWcfServiceClient();
   string name = "HasEmptyGuid";

   System.GUID guid = proxy.GetGUID(name);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For GetGUID()...

```
Assert.IsFalse(guid == Guid.Empty);
```

Similarly for GetEmptyGUID()...

```
Assert.IsTrue(guid == Guid.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this for a few months last year, IIRC isn't there an `Assert` class?  `Assert.IsTrue(...)`?

I've dropped VS test stuff in favor of other unit test frameworks (better IMO) so my memory is likely clouded.

Comment: Yeah its Assert.IsTrue(condition, "a message") or Assert.XXX(x, "a message").